# Displaying a Real-time img on HTML in IE10, 9 and 8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, caching, internet-explorer-10

Everyone.
I'm developing a webpage containing a real-time camera image.
So what I've tried is let  tag in HTML src keep add a random number like this:

```
setInterval(function () { document.getElementById("IMG").src = "/live_pic/XXX.jpg?time=" + new Date().getTime(); }, 300);
```

It works fine in IE11,Chrome and FireFox on Windows 7.
The XXX.jpg resource's content's changing 5 different real-time camera pictures per second.
And now here's the thing: 
It doesn't work in IE10, IE9 and IE8.
If I stop the "setInterval" function,
 displaying a fixed image on HTML are fine.
But once I try "setInterval" function, it can't find any resouce.
Is it about cache setting in IE?
I've tried adding  to set no-cache or no-store, like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-store" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />
```

It's still not working.
Can somebody give me any hint,please? Thanks a lot!

Comment: i would bet $100 that something else is causing your old IE to break, show us the rest.

Comment: really? ok I'll figure out other details about this.

Comment: Sounds like another syntax error. Are you absolutely sure there are none? Common things like trailing commas (`[1,2,3,]`) will break IE8.